# can't access public_html & wp_config.php in free ftp cpanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

I create a free host & domain and upload  wordpress-4.2.4.tar and create a database  I can't access some file in using ftp client 
< and when  i want  Log in to my panel  i can't access create new user and ftp account

Comment: Limitations of the free host perhaps?  What specific error do you get when attempting to access via ftp?

Comment: If you can't provide any further info you will need to contact the host provider.